# Xcode Declaration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

it says 'gameLoop' undeclared. can anyone correct this please?

```
(void) gameLoop {
        if(gameState == kGameStateRunning) {
            playerScoreText.hidden = YES;
            computerScoreText.hidden = YES;


            winOrLoseLabel.hidden = YES;

            ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x + ballVelocity.x , ball.center.y + ballVelocity.y);

            if(ball.center.x > self.view.bounds.size.width || ball.center.x < 0) {
                ballVelocity.x =- ballVelocity.x;
            }

            if(ball.center.y > self.view.bounds.size.height || ball.center.y < 0) {
                ballVelocity.y =- ballVelocity.y;
            }

            if (CGRectIntersectsRect (ball.frame, playerPaddle.frame)) {
                CGRect frame = ball.frame;
                frame.origin.x = playerPaddle.frame.origin.x - frame.size.height;
                ball.frame = frame;
                ballVelocity.x =- ballVelocity.x;
            }
```

Comment: Could you please post more of your code. And, fix it in the editor here.

Comment: you need to show the call to gameloop

Comment: You should post exact error messages or warnings where possible. And showing more of your code would help.

Comment: Is the method declared in your header file? Are you calling the method in a different class?

Comment: sorry, i added more code. im a new obj-c coder

Answer (score 2):

Have you declared the gameLoop method in your source header file? If you haven't, calling the gameLoop method from another class or from the same class (earlier on in the file) could cause this problem.

So you'd add this to your header file:

```
- (void)gameLoop;
```

For bonus points: If gameLoop is 'private' to your class (i.e. other classes don't need to call it) you could declare it in an empty 'extension' category at the top of the .m file.